# Tikz / LaTeX Indian Calendar

Tags: tikz-pgf, calendar

There are many calendar templates out there but it did not give me good ideas on how to create the one for my requirement. Indian calendar has lot more information on days other than just the numbers.
I would appreciate your ideas on how to proceed on this issue. I worked with tikz before but just enough to create a table etc. I don't know how to create a box for each day and also put some text into it. 
thanks for your help
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a bit of a translation? What makes the 3rd a red, how is it determined? What is a Chitra etc. Is there an algorithm to work all these out?

Comment: Can you provide more details on the calendar? Why ist Jan 1st missing, why Jan 30th & 31st?
Do all months look the same in their layout? Based on the rounded corners I would probably have a closer look at PGF/TikZ and its node feature. A while ago I used it to draw the keys of my calculator http://uweziegenhagen.de/?p=1453

Comment: yes there are some programs that spit out a csv file.

Comment: The `pgfcalendar` package used in conjunction with TikZ can do this very easily.  There are a couple of worked out examples in the TikZ documentation that should get you started. Alternatively, the `datatool` package along with TikZ might be better if the data is in CSV format.

Comment: You will need to provide much more information if you want the community here to help you. A reply such as ... there are some programs that spit out a csv file has an information value of zero.

Comment: @Yiannis- I will upload the csv file and yes the 3rd red is a festival worth highlighting. However I am not aware of the criteria. I will check with the person who will give me the csv file. I will try to gather as much info as I can and soon update either the comment or question. Thanks for your help.